# .htacces issue, showing directory page instead welcome page in laravel 5.7

Tags: xampp, laravel-5.7

Newly installed `laravel 5.7` show [directory page instead welcome page](https://prnt.sc/mfjyzp). I tried to shift .htaccess and index file from public folder to root folder then I got this error

```
Warning: require(E:\xampp\htdocs\auth_testing/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\xampp\htdocs\auth_testing\index.php on line 24

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 
'E:\xampp\htdocs\auth_testing/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='E:\xampp\php\PEAR') in E:\xampp\htdocs\auth_testing\index.php on line 24
```

I have also tried to change the .htaccess from the one shipped with laravel 5.7 to

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php

</IfModule>
```

I have also tried few others but no success, can somebody tell me permanent solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

In your Apache config (`E:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf`?), set the DocumentRoot to point to your project's `public/` folder (`E:\xampp\htdocs\auth_testing\public`?), then restart Apache.

If you've set up Virtual Hosts for each site, it might be in `E:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`.

You don't don't need to edit the default .htaccess file or move any other files in your Laravel project for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it after moving the `.htaccess` and index file from public to root I just change the

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

to

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

`:)`

Answer (score 0):

change htaccess to below

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>


RewriteEngine On



 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```